# How can I make specific DIVs resize on window resize for a responsive layout?

Tags: css, web, css-float, responsive-design

Here's the code i'm working with.

http://jsfiddle.net/qLjgM/2/

Basically, as the browser window is resized (getting smaller). I'm trying to force the 2 divs (MIDDLE 2-COLUMN and MIDDLE 3-COLUMN) to resize untill it hits a minimum size width of 200px for MIDDLE 3-COLUMN and 300px for MIDDLE 2-COLUMN.

```
#wrapper {
margin:0 auto;
width:100%;
max-width:500px;
}

#content-pad {
width:100%;
max-width:500px;
margin:0px;
background:#CCC;
font-size:12px;
}

#left-col {
float:left;
width:100px;
margin-top:12px;
background:#CCC;
}

#mid-col {
float:left;
width:100%;
min-width:200px;
max-width:270px;
margin-left:15px;
margin-top:12px;
background:#CCC;
}

#mid-col-wide {
float:left;
width:100%;
min-width:300px;
max-width:385px;
margin-left:15px;
margin-top:12px;
background:#CCC;
}

#right-col {
float:left;
width:100px;
margin-left:15px;
margin-top:12px;
background:#CCC;
}
```

I'm using float to align them inline so to speak, but it gives me trouble with the columns to the right just snapping below the LEFT SIDE and I want to avoid that as well.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Responsive design usually implies using media queries to change CSS as the window size changes. I don't see that there. The floats behave as I'd expect.

Comment: Yes, the media queries would take effect upon reaching the min-width limit. I dont want to use media queries based on resolutions but only when the layout is forced to break. Thanks!

Comment: I'm still not getting it. You have min-width set, yet you also have {width: 100%;}, which would seem to be contradictory.

Comment: I'm no CSS savant, but how's that contradictory? {width:100%} causes it to expand to it's maximum potential. And i have {min and max} width's set in order to prevent it from getting bigger than #px and smaller than #px.

Comment: When you have the width set to 100% like that, the element will prioritize being as wide as possible at all costs, even if it means other elements wrap around it.  It won't start resizing to its min-width until its parent forces it to do so:  http://jsfiddle.net/P4t5J/

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're giving your floats a width of 100% of their parents, which is #content-pad. This fails to account for the space taken up by #left-col, and therefore the floats are too wide to flow as you'd like. Try something like this, with fewer floats:

http://jsfiddle.net/qLjgM/5/

```
#wrapper { margin:0 auto; width:100%; max-width:500px; }
#content-pad { margin:0px; overflow: auto; }
#left-col { float:left; width:100px; margin-top:12px; margin-right: 10px; }
#mid-col { min-width:200px; margin-left:15px; margin-top:12px; }
#mid-col-wide { min-width:300px; margin-left:15px; margin-top:12px; }
#right-col { float:right; width:100px; margin-left:15px; margin-top:12px; }

        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="content-pad">
                <div id="left-col">LEFT SIDE
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <br />
                </div><!-- //left-col -->

                <div id="mid-col-wide">MIDDLE 2-COLUMN</div><!-- //mid-col -->
                <div id="right-col">RIGHT SIDE</div><!-- //mid-col -->
                <div id="mid-col">MIDDLE 3-COLUMN</div><!-- //mid-col -->
            </div><!-- //content-pad -->
        </div><!-- //wrapper -->
```

Comment: Thanks isherwood, this helps alot. I got it working as you have, now i'm just attempting to make mid-col start resizing before right-col overlaps it. But this gives me a great start. Thanks again!